# Python VTK - Picked points not accurate

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to build a software for drawing freeform shapes using VTK's interaction system, but it has an issue with the picked coordinates being placed where they don't belong. See the GIF below for what I mean:

[image]

when I save the coordinates and plot it elsewhere, the figure matches the points that were drawn on the screen (the red dots), as opposed to where I drew with the mouse (i.e., I don't get a circle from that third drawing.

MWE follows:

```
from vtkmodules.all import *
colors = vtkNamedColors()


class AnnotatorView:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.renderer = vtkRenderer()
        self.render_window = vtkRenderWindow()
        self.render_window.AddRenderer(self.renderer)
        self.render_window.SetWindowName('Annotator')
        self.render_window.SetSize(800, 800)

        self.interactor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        self.interactor.SetRenderWindow(self.render_window)

        self.create_background()

    def create_background(self, width=800, height=800):
        image_data = vtkImageData()
        image_data.SetDimensions(width, height, 1)
        image_data.AllocateScalars(VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 1)

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                gradient = y / 800.0
                image_data.SetScalarComponentFromFloat(x, y, 0, 0, gradient * 255)

        actor = vtkImageActor()
        actor.GetMapper().SetInputData(image_data)
        self.renderer.AddActor(actor)

    def add_point_actor(self, image_coordinates, point_size=2):
        """ Add a sphere at the given image coordinates """
        source = vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(image_coordinates[0], image_coordinates[1], 0)
        source.SetRadius(point_size)

        mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an panel_actor
        actor = vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)
        actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Red"))
        actor.GetProperty().SetDiffuse(1)
        actor.GetProperty().SetSpecular(1)
        self.renderer.AddActor(actor)
        return actor   


class AnnotatorInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleImage):
    def __init__(self, view, parent=None):
        self.is_dragging = False
        self.is_annotating = False
        self.dragged_points = []
        self.view = view

        self.AddObserver('LeftButtonPressEvent', self.left_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver('KeyPressEvent', self.key_press_event)
        self.AddObserver('LeftButtonReleaseEvent', self.left_button_release_event)
        self.AddObserver("MouseMoveEvent", self.on_mouse_move_event)

    def key_press_event(self, obj, event):
        key = self.view.interactor.GetKeySym()
        if key == "a":
            self.is_annotating = True
        if key == "s":
            self.is_annotating = False

    def left_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        if self.is_annotating:
            self.is_dragging = True

    def left_button_release_event(self, obj, event):
        if self.is_annotating:
            self.is_dragging = False

    def on_mouse_move_event(self, obj, event):
        if self.is_dragging:
            (mouseX, mouseY) = self.GetInteractor().GetEventPosition()
            # print(f'event position: {mouseX} , {mouseY}', flush=True)
            picker = vtkPointPicker()
            picker.Pick(mouseX, mouseY, 0.0, self.view.renderer)
            coords = picker.GetPickPosition()
            # print(f"image coords: {coords}")

            self.dragged_points.append(coords)
            self.view.add_point_actor(coords)
            self.view.render_window.Render()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("START")
    view = AnnotatorView()

    interactor_style = AnnotatorInteractorStyle(view)
    view.interactor.SetInteractorStyle(interactor_style)

    view.renderer.ResetCamera()
    view.render_window.Render()
    view.interactor.Initialize()
    view.interactor.Start()

    print("DONE")
```

Is this a VTK issue or is my code just not opimized?